# Area under the infinite tetration curve

Tags: definite-integrals, lambert-w, tetration, power-towers

What is the area under the curve where the infinite power tower converges?

$$\lim_{y \to \infty} = {}^y x.$$

The formula for this curve is given by various sources as:

$$\frac{\mathrm{W}(-\ln x)}{-\ln x}.$$

And the limits are from $\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{e}}$ to $\mathrm{e}^{\frac1{\mathrm{e}}}$.  So we have:

$$\int_{\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{e}}}^{\mathrm{e}^{\frac1{\mathrm{e}}}} \frac{\mathrm{W}(-\ln x)}{-\ln x} \,\mathrm{d}x.$$

Numerically this value is approximately $1.244131300633398$.

Is there an exact value for this integral known?

[image]

[Tetration wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration)

[Lambert's W Function wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

Comment: My motivation is simply idle curiosity.

Comment: Can you add a few links: one for Lambert W and one for ${}^yx$? Would be nice of you :)

Comment: As requested, I have added a link to the Wikipedia pages for these functions to the bottom of the question.

Comment: By the [inverse integral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions) this is equivalent to computing $\int_{1/e}^e t^{1/t} \, dt$. Which smells non elementary to me (e.g., it's reminiscent of the [sophomore's dream](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SophomoresDream.html) integral).

Comment: Are you certain that is the correct inverse integral?  The numerical value of that integral seems to be 2.65.

Comment: Right, and $2.65+1.24\approx e \cdot e^{1/e} - \frac{1}{e} \cdot e^{-e}$. (If the initial integral computes the area below the curve, its inverse integral computes the area to the left of the curve...)

Comment: Sorry, of course, that was a bit stupid of me. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Micah](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2685469/area-under-the-infinite-tetration-curve#comment5546257_2685469):

Since we know that

$$y=x^y\implies x=y^{1/y}$$

the inverse of the function is given by $x^{1/x}$, hence we have

$$\int_{\exp(-e)}^{\exp(1/e)}x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}~dx=\exp\left(1+\frac1e\right)-\exp(-1-e)-\int_{1/e}^ex^{1/x}~dx$$

Note that there is no known closed form for the integral on the right, even though it is in a much more manageable form. Numerically, the integral is given by [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int(x%3D1%2Fe,e,x%5E(1%2Fx))) as $\approx2.658607452339$, so

> $$\int_{\exp(-e)}^{\exp(1/e)}x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}~dx\approx1.2441313006$$