# Integral with Lambert $W$ function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, lambert-w, tetration

I'm trying to calculate the integral of the infinite tetration of $x$ where it's defined,

$$\displaystyle\int_{e^{-e}}^{e^{1/e}}x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{...}}}}}dx$$

which simplifies to
$\displaystyle\int_{e^{-e}}^{e^{1/e}}\frac{W(-\ln x)}{-\ln x}\,dx$ or $\displaystyle\int_{-1/e}^{e}\frac{W(u)}{u}e^{-u}\,du$. However, I don't know where to go from there. I'm sure there isn't an elementary antiderivative but WolframAlpha says it's about $1.244$.

Comment: This doesn't have a full answer, but [does this help](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerTower.html)?

Comment: $\displaystyle=\int_{-1}^1(1+x)e^{-xe^x}\,dx.$

Comment: Sorry, but does this answer your question? [Integral over domain of infinite tetration of x over extended domain from 0 to $\sqrt[e]e$. Possible $\int_{e^{-e}}^{e^\frac1e} x^{x^{…}}dx$ solution.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4168572/integral-over-domain-of-infinite-tetration-of-x-over-extended-domain-from-0-to)